# Caching Multiple Dynamically Generated Regex Expressions to Disk

Tags: c#, regex, caching

I have a program that I'm working on which uses a very large number ( >100) of dynamically generated Regex expressions. Each regex is being used against a large number of strings (depending on the situation, this can be > 2k), so I have them compiled, and cache their use internally. However, the program gets run repeatidly (it's part of a build tool), and the compiling of those dynamically generated expressions takes a significant amount of time every time the program starts. I already have an on-disk cache (no parsing is required if the cache is valid), and could store the compiled Regex expressions in it, however I can't seem to figure out a way to do this correctly. I first thought of using Regex.CompileToAssembly, but Mono doesn't support it, and the program needs to run on Mono as well as MS.net. Because of that I can't figure out a good way of caching the expressions. I only need the IsMatch(string) method from the compiled Regex, and I do have the option of modifying the Mono Regex implementation and including it in my program, but I have no idea where to start with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite a full solution, but I was able to use binary serialization to produce a noticable improvement in startup time with the cache vs. without. I suspect most of this is actually just time it's saving parsing the regex, and that it's still having to do the actual compiling, but it's a good enough difference for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You may create another program, that will compile expression in a build step. And then supply already compiled assemblies with your project. That will eliminate the problem of not supported Regex.CompileToAssembly on Mono.

Comment: Unfortunately, since the Regex expressions are generated at runtime, this isn't an option.

Comment: Then create a remote compilation service hosted on Windows, that will return assemblies from regex strings :)

Comment: Last I checked, all the existing build tools (this is actually something similar to standard make, but with features that allow a single makefile to be used for multiple platforms) out there don't require an internet connection to function. Plus, the functions that the compiled assemblies depend on throw not implemented exceptions in mono.

Comment: I was just thinking of ideas. Hm, then I see only one option, but you won't like it either: replace your regex with custom search code, generate it the way you need and compile dynamically.